# Topic does not exist - LocalStack SNS unit test

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, quarkus, amazon-sns, localstack

I created a class (code below) to mock a Sns with localstack:

```
public class SnsResource implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {

    private static final DockerImageName LOCALSTACK_IMAGE_NAME = DockerImageName
            .parse("localstack/localstack").withTag("0.14.3");

    private LocalStackContainer container;

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> start() {
        DockerClientFactory.instance().client();
        try {
            container = new LocalStackContainer(LOCALSTACK_IMAGE_NAME).withServices(LocalStackContainer.Service.SNS);
            container.start();

            URI endpointOverride = container.getEndpointOverride(LocalStackContainer.Service.SNS);

            SnsClient client = createClient(endpointOverride);

            String topicName = "notify-email-received";
            createSnsTopic(client, topicName);

            return generatePropertiesMapToOverride(endpointOverride);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not start Sns localstack server", e);
        }
    }

    @NotNull
    private Map<String, String> generatePropertiesMapToOverride(final URI endpointOverride) {
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();

        properties.put("quarkus.sns.endpoint-override", endpointOverride.toString());
        properties.put("quarkus.sns.aws.region", "us-east-1");
        properties.put("quarkus.sns.aws.credentials.type", "static");
        properties.put("quarkus.sns.aws.credentials.static-provider.access-key-id", "accessKey");
        properties.put("quarkus.sns.aws.credentials.static-provider.secret-access-key", "secretKey");

        return properties;
    }

    private SnsClient createClient(final URI endpointOverride) {
        return SnsClient.builder()
                .endpointOverride(endpointOverride)
                .credentialsProvider(
                        StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create("accesskey", "secretKey")))
                .httpClientBuilder(UrlConnectionHttpClient.builder())
                .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
                .build();
    }

    private void createSnsTopic(final SnsClient snsClient, final String topicName) {
        try {
            snsClient.createTopic(topicRequest -> topicRequest.name(topicName));
            System.out.println("SNS Topic Created: " + topicName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating SNS Topic: " + topicName, e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        if (container != null) {
            container.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using @QuarkusTestResource(SnsResource.class) at my test class.

When I run the test that calls the method that publish to Sns I get the following error:

**UUID: a5db493a-baae-44aa-a2e1-a5d1f232f75d, publishMailNotify: error to send sns topic: Topic does not exist (Service: Sns, Status Code: 404, Request ID: Z1FAOJJRTMBQLZJGY2XEH0VNZ0JN455BHXGDYYJM2U3CXG0UFZ2B, Extended Request ID: null)
software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.model.NotFoundException: Topic does not exist (Service: Sns, Status Code: 404, Request ID: Z1FAOJJRTMBQLZJGY2XEH0VNZ0JN455BHXGDYYJM2U3CXG0UFZ2B, Extended Request ID: null)**

I really don't know how to do. Searched the web for similar problems but didnt find anything.

I am using Java 11 with Quarkus.